# handling useEffect and server side changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to confirm that a new user has a unique nickname or not. And if it is not unique i want to show a message to user. For that reason i wrote that code:

```
const [vNicknameServer, setvNicknameServer] = useState(true);
```

...

```
const validateNicknameServer = async (nickname) => {
    let flag = 0;
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .where("nickname", "==", nickname)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          if (documentSnapshot.data().nickname == nickname) {
            setvNicknameServer(false); //Changing state
            flag = 1;
          }
        });
        if (flag == 0) {
          setvNicknameServer(true); // changing state
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

....

```
{vNickname ? (
  <Text style={{ color: "#DC8989" }}>
    Nickname min 4 max 14 caracters
  </Text>
) : vNicknameServer == false ? ( // according to state it appears or not
  <Text style={{ color: "#DC8989" }}>Nickname must be unique</Text>
) : null}
```

But the render process always done after some other process. I should use useEffect but i am a little bit confused how to use it in there? Anyone can help me to use it?

---

Note:

This validation made it in a submit handler :

```
const Submit = () => {
    validateEmail(email) ? setvEmail(false) : setvEmail(true);
    validateNickname(nickname) ? setvNickname(false) : setvNickname(true);
    validatePassword(password) ? setvPassword(false) : setvPassword(true);
    validateNicknameServer(nickname);
    console.log(vEmailServer);
    console.log(email);
    if (
      validateEmail(email) &&
      validateNickname(nickname) &&
      validatePassword(password) &&
      vNicknameServer &&
      vEmailServer
    ) {
      navigation.navigate("UserCredential", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        nickname: nickname,
      });
    }
  };
```

I want to control it just when i clicked the button not in every case.

NOTE: Please check the below answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to use an async in a `useEffect` hook. To do that, you can use the following pattern

```js
// probably need to setup a useState hook to contain nickname data
const [nickname, setNickname] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  // get nickname from the component state instead of passing the data as a param
  const validateNicknameServer = async () => {
    let flag = 0;
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .where("nickname", "==", nickname)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          if (documentSnapshot.data().nickname == nickname) {
            setvNicknameServer(false); //Changing state
            flag = 1;
          }
        });
        if (flag == 0) {
          setvNicknameServer(true); // changing state
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  validateNicknameServer();
}, [nickname])
```

#### Update based on the note

I can't verify if it runs without any error. But hopefully, it provides some ideas for you to solve the issue.

```js
const validateNicknameServer = async (nickname) => {
  let flag = 0;
  const querySnapshot = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .where("nickname", "==", nickname)
    .get()
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
    if (documentSnapshot.data().nickname == nickname) {
      setvNicknameServer(false); //Changing state
      flag = 1;
      return false
    }
  });
  if (flag == 0) {
    setvNicknameServer(true); // changing state
    return true
  }
};

const Submit = async () => {
  // .... other code
  // validate the name before navigation happens
  // and use vNicknameServer to displaying messages
  const isValidName = await validateNicknameServer(nickname);
  // .... other code
  if (
    validateEmail(email) &&
    validateNickname(nickname) &&
    validatePassword(password) &&
    isValidName &&
    vEmailServer
  ) {
    navigation.navigate("UserCredential", {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      nickname: nickname,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you check the edit i added some more infos

Comment: I think that but if i made handler async then in every clicked, the button response async, isn't it ?

Comment: @LeoS yes. the response will be async. We are waiting for the `validateNicknameServer` to be completed before we decide if navigation should be executed. Is this the behavior you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `useEffect`, and use `for in` instead `forEach` for easy control the flow.

```
const validateNicknameServer = async (nickname) => {
  await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .where("nickname", "==", nickname)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      for (var documentSnapshot in querySnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.data().nickname == nickname) {
          return false;
        }
      }
       
      return true;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

const Submit = async () => {
  // Other validation ...

  // Waiting validate nickname on server. Should display loading state for better UX.
  const validateNicknameServer = await validateNicknameServer(nickname);
    
  // Change state after validate
  setvNicknameServer(false);

  // Form valid -> Navigate to UserCredential screen 
  if (
    validateEmail(email) &&
    validateNickname(nickname) &&
    validatePassword(password) &&
    vEmailServer
    validateNicknameServer &&     
  ) {
    navigation.navigate("UserCredential", {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      nickname: nickname,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of submit you're doing async operation but not waiting for it that's why

> render process always done after some other process

So submit method's **if**'s code will execute before **validateNicknameServer**'s async operation is completed.

I think You don't need to use **useEffect** here.
also after **setvNicknameServer()** whole component is gonna re-render so Submit method still gonna have vNicknameServer's previous value even if you've updated it.

Here's what you can do

For method **validateNicknameServer** when using await you should use **try/catch** instead of **then/catch**

```
const validateNicknameServer = async (nickname) => {
  let flag = 0;
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Users')
      .where('nickname', '==', nickname)
      .get();

    querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
      if (documentSnapshot.data().nickname == nickname) {
        flag = 1;
      }
    });

    return flag == 0 ? true : false;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return false;
};
```

now in **Submit** method wait for **validateNicknameServer** to complete and same for other methods (validateEmail, validateNickname, validatePassword) too if they're also asynchronous.

```
const Submit = async () => {
  validateEmail(email) ? setvEmail(false) : setvEmail(true);
  validateNickname(nickname) ? setvNickname(false) : setvNickname(true);
  validatePassword(password) ? setvPassword(false) : setvPassword(true);
  // wait for this method to complete, same for above methods too if they are async
  const isNickNameUnique = await validateNicknameServer(nickname);
  setvNicknameServer(isNickNameUnique);
  console.log(vEmailServer);
  console.log(email);
  if (
    validateEmail(email) &&
    validateNickname(nickname) &&
    validatePassword(password) &&
    isNickNameUnique &&
    vEmailServer
  ) {
    navigation.navigate('UserCredential', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      nickname: nickname,
    });
  }
};
```

here these type of operations are expected to be async so it's best practice to show **LoadingIndicator** to the user while waiting.